# Creating complex Conditional Formatting rules

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have several models listed in the Google spreadsheet. Suppose that they are divided into "Standard" and "Extended" types. They also have other parameters, such as a value of `10` or `20`.

I want to get appropriate backgrounds and fonts using conditional formatting. For example: "Standard" uses a red background, while "Extended" uses a blue background.

This simple example works great, but the problem starts when I want to apply more complex formatting, e.g. any model type (both Standard and Extended) with parameter `20` use a bold font: when I add a third formatting rule, the cell background overwrites.

Is there any solution to this problem?

I will add that it is not possible to add rules such as: 20 AND Standard, 20 AND Extended etc ... because in reality the combination of model types is much larger.

Comment: can you show what you did and how your spreadsheet is formatted?

Comment: Only one rule can be active for a given cell at a time

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@tehhowch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50277112/creating-complex-conditional-formatting-rules#comment87996823_50277112):

[The first rule found to be true will define the format of the cell or range.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Instead of laying rules on top of one another you would need separate rules for each situation.